# PhpStorm debug stack frame colours explanation

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, stack-frame

This picture shows an example of the 'Frames' pane in PhpStorm while in debug mode:

[image]

I have not found any explanation of the colours in the PhpStorm documentation and I wanted to know their meaning. Why some are green, other yellow and most of them white? Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those *should be* colors from File Colors settings (applies not just here, but in many other places where files are involved, e.g. Project View panel, Navigate To File, Search results, even editor tabs -- all depends how you have configured that).

Based on your screenshot you have default colors for 2 default built-in scopes:

- **Green:** your Tests
- **Yellow:** excluded/out-of-project/library files (e.g. Symfony framework, Twig library, SwiftMailer library etc -- whatever you have in your `vendor/` folder).

You can add your own colors: just define custom Scope that will include certain files/folders (exact or pattern based match), save it and then add a color entry.

[image]

Check these links:

- Main article (how-to): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html
- Scopes screen: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-scopes.html
- File Colors screen: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-file-colors.html

Play with those and see how it works / what the changes you will get.